# Most efficient way to copy elements from multidimensional array to flat array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional Array in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="country_array">
<item>
    <country>Afghanistan</country>
    <code>AF</code>
    <prefix>088</prefix>
</item>
<item>
    <country>Albania</country>
    <code>AL</code>
    <prefix>068</prefix>
</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Basically, I need this string-array to let users select a country and then access other data of these countries like their country code etc., but Android's Spinner element doesn't like multidimensional arrays, but only flat ones. :/

So I am fighting with the question: what is the most efficient way to create a new array that just consists of the first elements of my multidimensional array (the country names)?

I could then use the flat array for Android's spinner adapter and retrieve the other values easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SAXParser](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/) to populate a string array with known size. This XML Parser works very fast and it will be a good approach from my point of view.

Just make an index variable, and when parser reaches an xml `country` tag, get the tag text and set it to the relevant string array item. After that increase index, doing `index++`.

That's it and it should work perfectly for you.

Comment: I just took a look at the documentation, but it looks as SAXParser would be a relatively complex way to 'simply' copy array elements? I saw examples of how to do it in PHP etc., usually one- to three-liners of code (which at least to me as a beginner looks efficient). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem anything like that in Java. :/

Comment: If source format won't change and is hard-coded, then just use a loop to parse your xml, reading character after character from the source string, and assign the country names to array elements.